# Get title,url and image from flickr using flickr api,

Tags: javascript, get, flickr

I could not figure out what I am doing wrong?

Also i am having problem storing data in javascript 2d array.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n529qwnb/27/)

```
 $.getJSON(url,

  function (data) {
      /*Insert your titles you wanna show*/
      var titles = ["box closing", "e"];
      var nope = [
          [],
          [],
          []
      ];



      // var len = titles.length;
      var count = 0;
      var col = 0;
      var row=0;
      $.each(data.photos.photo, function (i, item) {
          var purl = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_m.jpg';

          // var pid = item.id;
          var container = '<tr><td class="col-md-8"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/' + userid + '/' + item.id + '/"><img class="span4" alt="' + item.title + '" src="' + purl + ' width=100 height=200"/></td></tr>';


          var title = '<tr><td class="col-md-4" >' + item.title + '</td></tr>';

          nope[row][0] = item.title;
          nope[row][1] = container;
          nope[row][2]=title;



          /*Show only image with in titles*/
          if (item.title == titles[count]) {
              $(container).appendTo('#contain');
              $(title).appendTo('#contain');
              //$("a.imageurl").append(" ");
              //$("#name").append(title);
              //$("a.imageurl").append(purl);
              //$("a.imageurl").append(" ");
              //purl = '
              $("#demo").append(nope[row][col]);
              $("#demo").append(nope[row][col]);
              $("#demo").append(nope[row][col]);
          }
          col++;
          count = count + 1;
      });
  });
```

Comment: there is a reason you cannot post a jsfiddle without code. You need to post code here. Also you have TWO questions. What are your SPECIFIC issues with expected result

Comment: In the javascript code             
 $("#demo").append(nope[row][col]);
is not showing up in output(i.e. 'div' with id 'demo'.

Comment: What - Please tell expected output and actual output

Comment: I am expecting 
title,
image,
url.
showing data[][] array.

Comment: And what is it showing instead?

Comment: You have some weird col and row array, why? Why not just `$("#demo").append(itemt.title);` You are not telling us WHAT you want to show, only that your code is not showing what you are not telling us you want to see

Comment: actually I am appending array data into table,
for each entry a row/column should be created and inserted into table.
I have to sort the values so I created array.

Comment: @mplungjan
It should be like:
$("#demo").append(nope[row][0]);
$("#demo").append(nope[row][1]);
$("#demo").append(nope[row][2]);
because row is changing after every iteration.

If I run this I get output in weird way, 
for example:
title1, image1, 
title1, image1, 
title2, title2.